# Can C programming language handle 10^100

Tags: c

What is the biggest number that the C programming language data type can handle.
If it can handle 10^100 will it be using long double?

And what's the maximum number that java programming language can handle and using which data type?

Comment: Do you mean 10 * 100 == 1,000? I'm puzzled.

Comment: Are you looking for "built-in" types only? Both languages have the ability to create your own numeric objects that can hold arbitrarily sized numbers.

Comment: Do you mean 10 ^ 100 / 10 ** 100 = 1 followed by 100 zeroes? I don't want to edit it, just in case.

Comment: If only there were some kind of reference book or Internet search engine available with which you could look up data types for these obscure languages.... Good thing we have SO!

Answer (score 3):

The largest number that can be represented with a Standard C basic type is

`LDBL_MAX`

defined in `float.h` and of `long double` type.

`LDBL_MAX` value is implementation defined but has to be greater or equal to `1e+37`.

When `long double` type is used to represent `IEEE 754-2008` quadruple precision type (`binary128`), `LDBL_MAX` value is around `1.189731e+4932`

Answer (score 0):

```
            #ifdef __18CXX
        typedef signed char int8_t;                 // -128 -> 127               // Char & Signed Char
        typedef unsigned char uint8_t;              // 0 -> 255                  // Unsigned Char
        typedef signed short int int16_t;           // -32768 -> 32767           // Int
        typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;        // 0 -> 65535                // Unsigned Int
        typedef signed short long int int24_t;      // -8388608 -> 8388607       // Short Long
        typedef unsigned short long int uint24_t;   // 0 -> 16777215             // Unsigned Short Long
        typedef signed long int int32_t;            // -2147483648 -> 2147483647 // Long
        typedef unsigned long int uint32_t;         // 0 -> 4294967295           // Unsigned Long
        #else
        #   include <stdint.h>
        #endif
```

Comment: I think this is what you are searching for...

Comment: 10x100 you just need an int16 or uint16. But of course you could declare a variable of a unsigned long int (uint32) but it's not nessesary!

Answer (score 0):

In 64-bit systems, the 64-bit unsigned integer data type can handle numbers up to `2^64-1`. This is much larger than `10*100` which is `1000`. However, I presume you mean `10^100`, which is far larger than any native integer data type in any practical architecture. To manipulate such data types you must use a `big integer` or `BigInt` data type.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the precision and accuracy you want for numbers that big.

You can trawl through `<limits.h>` which should have all the relevant constants.